radius detail of corner of stub beam web
existing repair on stub beams beneath the passenger cabin floor is characterized as following:
"The existing repair must have removed the radius detail of the lower
inboard corner of the stub beam web"
Do you have any idea on what "radius detail" means?



This has nothing to do with Aviation, as defined in the Help Center.

this is about internal structure of 737-300

General terminology about structures, even structures used in an aircraft, is off topic, just as questions about food, even food prepared & served on an aircraft, would be off-topic.
